# PYTHON-The value of property "{field_name}" is longer than 1048487 bytes for TextProperty in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

According to cloud datastore documentation for field type `TextProperty` there shouldn't be any restriction on size but in my case it's giving below error for string size equal to

> The value of property "{my_field_name}" is longer than 1048487 bytes

Below is my entity class

```
class History(ndb.Model):
    user_mail = ndb.StringProperty()
    json_string = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
    updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

This is function from where I am trying to store the entity

```
def store_user_mail(user_email, json_object):

    # string size for which this is creating problem is around 1.56Mb
    print(sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(json_object)))

    user_mail_obj = History()
    user_mail_obj.user_mail = user_email
    user_mail_obj.json_string = json.dumps(json_object)
    user_mail_obj.updated_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    user_mail_obj.put()
```

Also I have tried compression of the json string before storing but that would create problem for us because we want to store this as text property not as binary data.

Also point is as my `json_string` field is **TextProperty** type it should be stored without any issue irrespective of size of string. Have already spent a lot of time figuring out solution. Is there something which I am doing wrong here or is this bug with **NDB** or **datastore** and if that's the case what can be a good solution ?

Comment: What is the value of `my_field_name`?

Comment: Also, why not use `ndb.JsonProperty`? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types

Comment: @hjpotter92  value of  `my_field_name` is `json_string`

Comment: @hjpotter92 tried that but in datastore that will store json as binary not as text string and as mentioned we want to store that as a string

Comment: @DanCornilescu My bad !! Actually cloud datastore is what I wanted to say. Also below is link of documentation [TextProperty Documentation Link For Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Python_Properties_and_value_types). I think maybe I got the point now we can have unlimited length of string with `TextProperty` but still size constraint would be there of 1500 Bytes which was actually missing in doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the TextProperty, it is because the maximum size of a Datastore entity can be 1,048,572. 
 https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

I'm looking at BlobProperty for you.... looks like maybe that is still a 1MB limit (I can't confirm), but you can use a **compress** argument to get a lot more than 1MB of data into it.

Comment: How to use a compress argument ?

Answer (score 1):

Entities have a 1MB size limit. If what you are trying to store in an entity/property may be bigger than that then you need to use CloudStorage. I suggest storing that text as a file in Cloud Storage and keeping a link in a property of your object. It may look like this:

```
class History(ndb.Model):
    user_mail = ndb.StringProperty()
    url = ndb.StringProperty() #https://storage.googleapis.com/{app_id}/{file_name}
    updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

Then when you need that text you just have to read the file stored in that url.